# Heroku : Server Error, Status=(500), bytes=403

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

Everything in the project is working but I only have problem with this request and I dont know what it is.

heroku logs:

```
2021-11-30T19:23:21.705472+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.43.186 - - [30/Nov/2021:19:23:21 +0000] "GET /api/player=1/matches HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"   
2021-11-30T19:23:21.707787+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/player=1/matches" host=football-players-stats-api.herokuapp.com request_id=e94d6c13-3fbd-4825-b696-282992be5bc9 fwd="186.58.74.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=403 protocol=https
```

views:

```
class MatchesView(generics.ListAPIView): 
    serializer_class = MatchesSerializer    
    permissions      = (IsAuthenticated)        
    def get_queryset(self):    
        player = self.kwargs['player']            
        return Matches.objects.filter(player=player).all()
```

urls:

```
app_name = 'api'
urlpatterns = [    
    path('',include(router.urls)),
    path('player=<str:player>/matches',views.MatchesView)  
]
```

Comment: do you need to add `as_view()`. so `views.MatchesView.as_view()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is from a newer part of django im not familiar with, however I think one simply needs to change:

```
path('player=<str:player>/matches',views.MatchesView)
```

For this:

```
path('<str:player>/matches',views.MatchesView.as_view())
```

And even better still:

```
path('matches/<str:player>',views.MatchesView.as_view())
```

The third option seems to make more sense as a url. Perhaps you may want other urls around matches.

`matches/statistics` for example, or `matches/<str:player>/statistics/`

By adding the `player=` you essentially make the accessible URI `yourserver.com/api/player=PlayerName/matches`

When retrospectively this parameter would NEVER be introduced in this way at this part of the URL.

Parameters are always added at the end after the `?` and separated by `&` AND perhaps this is actually what you want to do, and in which case you would not have the `<str:player>` portion of the URL but instead would allow client side scripts add these parameters, or the API users, whichever is interacting with your view.

As a bonus round, you also don't need to do `queryset.filter().all()` because the `.all()` is redundant :)